# Numba - copy of a jitclass instance

Tags: python, copy, jit, deep-copy, numba

How can I make a copy of a `numba jitclass` instance (whose variables are `numpy` scalars and arrays)?

Is there a better way other than making a new instance and copying all variables in a loop? I also tried `copy.copy` and `copy.deepcopy`, but both fail with `TypeError: can't pickle MyJitClassName objects`

Answer (score 3):

I'd imagine in principle this is something `numba` could support (consider opening an [issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues)) but for now I think the only option is to define your own.

Note that jitclasses hold references to arrays, so if you want to copy the underlying data, the `array.copy()` is necessary.

```
from numba import jitclass, float64
spec = [
    ('scalar', float64),
    ('array', float64[:]),
]

@jitclass(spec)
class MyJitClass:
    def __init__(self, scalar, array):
        self.scalar = scalar
        self.array = array

    def copy(self):
        return MyJitClass(self.scalar, self.array.copy())
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, only initializing an empty new instance and looping on all vars in `specs` and checking `if isinstance(var, numba.types.npytypes.Array): setattr(new_instance, var, getattr(self, var).copy())`. As you mentioned that's not ideal